# .NET Core SignalR - Calling Hub Method in Singleton/From Service Provider

Tags: c#, .net-core, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a web app that is using .NET 6 using dependency-injected strongly-typed Hub method.

At the moment I have a single method that calls a `RefreshAll` method on the Hub, causing the web page to refetch my API using ajax.

The way I have my hub set up in my controllers is like this:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace TestProject;

public class MyController : Controller
{
   public MyController(IHubContext<MyRefreshHub, IMyRefreshHubClient> hub)
   {
      _hub = hub;
   }

   readonly IHubContext<MyRefreshHub, IMyRefreshHubClient> _hub;

   [HttpGet]
   public IActionResult Trigger()
   {
      // Tell SignalR to send the 'RefreshAll' command to all the listeners
      _hub.Clients.All.RefreshAll();
      return Ok();
   }
}
```

This works just fine and I am using this method in a lot of places in my app without any issue.

The problem comes when I want to trigger SignalR from a singleton. In my case, I have a singleton service that simply has a timer that goes off every 30 seconds. In the example below, I am using a `System.Timers.Timer`, but I have tried this method with `System.Threading.Timer` as well as using a `PeriodicTimer` to ensure it runs in a Task, all to no avail.

The singleton injects `IServiceProvider`, and when the timer goes off I am creating a new scope to allow the hub to live in (as well as a few other scoped services that I don't have in this example). This is similar to what it looks like:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace TestProject;

public class TimerService
{
   public TimerService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   {
      _serviceProvider = serviceProvider
      _timer = new(30 * 100);
      _timer.Elapsed += async (_, _) => await _SendRefresh();
   }

   readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
   readonly System.Timers.Timer _timer;
  
   async Task _SendRefresh()
   {
      using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
      var hub = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHubContext<MyRefreshHub, IMyRefreshHubClient>>();
      await hub.Clients.All.RefreshAll();
   }
}
```

I can set a breakpoint on the line that calls the refresh on the hub, and it hits that breakpoint, and moves on to the next breakpoint. However nothing happens and there is nothing sent my my server or received on my web page. Even setting the log settings as `trace` results in not a single output to my `Output` window, my terminal running the website that has site logs, nor my browser's javascript console. All of these places log sending a message through my controllers that work fine.

I'm a bit at a loss right now on where to look next. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

For refrence, here is how I am setting up my DI:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSignalR();

// Note: in my actual app I associate these with interfaces. Just trying to make this less complex in this example
services.AddScoped<MyController>();
services.AddSingleton<TimerService>();

// Start the timer service immediately after we've registered everything in DI
serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TimerService>();
...
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddNewtonsoftJson();
...

app.MapHub<MyRefreshHub>("/websockets/refresh_hub");

app.Run();
```

And here is my hub:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace TestProject;

public interface IMyRefreshHubClient
{
    Task RefreshAll();
}

public class MyRefreshHub : Hub<IMyRefreshHubClient>
{
    public async Task RefreshAll() =>
        await Clients.All.RefreshAll();
}
```

Comment: You can inject hub context in your TimerService.

Comment: I thought I wasn't able to since the hub is transient and the service is a singleton? Update: Was able to inject it, but no results. Still silently fails to send any SingalR events or even trace logs when I call `RefreshAll()`

Comment: It looks like you are creating a service provider manually to start your timer service. Is that true? If so, the timer service is likely in its "own world" which is why the IHubContext service isn't working. You should call GetRequiredService<TimerService>() from the service provider on WebApplication.

Comment: @Brennan I did make a mistake in my example (fixed now), but the `TimerService` is correctly being added to the services. Not in this example but in my real implementation, I am able to inject the `TimerService` into my controllers and interact (start + stop the timer via public methods in the service).

Is building the service provider then instantiating the timer service putting it in its own world? Is there a better way to initialize the service on instantiation?

Comment: `app.Services.GetRequiredService<TimerService>()`

Comment: @Brennan Nope still not working. Even if it was on a different instance, I would think that it would still log to my console (given my log settings for SignalR) and it should *still* work as in the end it's pointing to the same URL to open a websocket connection and send.